# Rule Builder - freehand SQL user entry

Tags: sql, sql-server, rule-engine, business-rules

I have some users who have a need to create some fairly complex rules with data from a SQL database. It's not enough to just have logical operators like most rule builders, because there's some aggregation/shaping required and the rules might change a fair bit over time.

We're trying to create a rule-builder that essentially allows users to input their own SQL query where the output would be boolean or numeric, which would determine what the rule does.

If any of you have built something like this before, I'm trying to research technologies for the template/sql commander and slick ways of incorporating their SQL rule in my workflow. Any recommendations/examples would be great.

Comment: This is generally a terrible idea. Business users do not know about performance and will certainly run inefficient queries - If you need self-service BI then look into creating a data model and publishing it either through something like PowerBI (great) or even Excel with pivot tables etc.

Comment: Hi - the users in this case are data analysts and the rules happen off-line (i.e. for internal workflow management), so inefficiency of queries is less of a concern than it might be otherwise. It's less about business intelligence than it is about If all of these things (which may be re-shaped, re-aggregated, nested conditions) are true/false then do X, where X is part of an already defined workflow.